# из С на Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, циклы

Слабо понимаю ассемблер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, код на ассемблере таких операций, написанных на [с](/questions/tagged/%d1%81):

тут желательно с `LOOP`

```
total = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i=i+1) total = total + 1;
```

и

```
if(counter > 10) then
    counter = 0;
else
    counter = counter + 1;
```

Comment: нужно на fasm ?

Comment: нет, просто аналогичный код, как R0=5 -> MOV R0,#5

Comment: Код будет такой, какой компилятор сделает. Поэтому нужно скомпилировать и дизассемблировать.

Comment: Так на каком ассемблере код то нужен ? Вы про какой то R0 говорите, а на архитектуре x86 например такого регистра нет (по крайней мере ax не принято называть R0). Такие регистры есть например на архитектуре S390, но там нет инструкции MOV. P.S. и да, очевидно, если total в регистре R0, то `mov R0, #4` это именно то что сделает нормальный современный оптимизирующий компилятор с вашим первым примером

Comment: меня лишь синтаксис интересует. Как правильно применить команды MOV  CMP ADD и LOOP

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda сек, ща приведу пример

Comment: Я спрашиваю про то, какая у вас архитектура. Сами наборы команд у разных процессоров разные. ну синтаксис разумеется свой. и команды совершенно по разному называются. на x86 процессорах все пересылки данных делаются mov. На S390 загрузка в регистр LR, а пересылка из регистра в память STH или STC

Comment: Я работаю с ARM Cortex-m0

Comment: Вот вам на заметку: https://gcc.godbolt.org Можете анализировать АСМ сишного и плюсового кода в реальном времени.

Comment: У ARM нет LOOP. Более того, у Cortex-m0 даже не полноценная система команд ARM, а Thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С циклом (все делал в `fasm`):

```
mov ecx,5 ;цикл loop работает с переменной ecx, задаем макс значение(минусуется пока ecx не будет равен 0)
mov ebx,0 ;регистр, куда записываются данные


l1:
add ebx,1 ;прибавляем единицу
loop l1 ;проверяется не равен ли ecx нулю, если нет, то минусуем и прыгаем на метку l1

;выводим результат
invoke wsprintfA, addr tr, addr Text, ebx
invoke MessageBox,0, addr tr, addr caption,0
```

С условием

```
mov eax,5 ;изначальный регистр
mov ebx,10 ;с чем сравнивать

cmp eax,ebx ;cmp -команда сравнения
jl m1 ;если eax меньше, чем ebx, то прыгаем на метку m1
;если же больше, то присваиваем eax значение 0
 mov eax,0
 jmp m2 ;прыгаем на метку m2, что бы не началось выполнение метки m1
m1:
  add eax,1 ;добавляем единицу к регистру eax
m2:
;выводим результат
invoke wsprintfA, addr tr, addr Text, eax
invoke MessageBox,0, addr tr, addr caption,0
```

Comment: а как цикл знает, когда ему остановится? мы ведь только присвоили значение регистру ecx

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda сейчас прокомментирую код

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda грубо прокомментировал код

Comment: а как именно loop работает с ecx?

Comment: @Lolidze А ничего что ТС использует систему команд процессоров ARM и там нет ни регистров eax и подобных, ни операций перехода, начинающихся на J

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda Вы же сказали, что у вас ARM. У этих процессоров нет регистра ecx и кстати нет инструкции loop (по крайней мере у моделей на которые я нашел описания)

Comment: названия команд меня не интересует, говорю же ,что это для меня не важно. А loop есть, кстати

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda яж написал, LOOP уменьшает на единицу содержимое ECX и производит переход, если содержимое не равно нулю

Comment: @Mike об этом я какт не подумал ))

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda Покажите доку где он описан, сейчас нашел для cortex. нет там loop. И заметьте, в x86 loop уменьшает ecx на 1 и пока он не 0 переходит по метке. но если на ARM все таки есть loop, то он может работать совершенно иначе !  И кстати, на x86 платформе ваш второй блок кода я бы написал например как `cmp eax, 9  /   mov eax, -2  / adc eax, 1` что бы избежать использования переходов.

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda Зато вижу у ARM отличные инструкции ... ваш второй пример должен выглядеть как то так: `cmp R0, #10  /   addgt  R0, R0, #1  /   movle  R0, #0`

Comment: где в loop написано, что именно у ECX мы отнимаем 1. Просто кроме команды MOV мы с этим регистром, вроде ,ничего не делаем. По крайней мере - я не вижу и не понимаю

Comment: @Mike Если можете, напишите код для x86

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda это автоматически происходит, для удобства создана готовая команда loop. Если хотите, то можете не использовать loop, а самому написать условие, где сравниваете ecx с 0, отнимаете у ecx единицу и прыгаете по метке

Comment: @AleitalaAmeda А где именно вы это читаете, где то в интернете или в каких нибудь учебниках/методичках. потому что loop и ecx есть только у x86 процессоров. А если вам дали задание написать для ARM то вам это совершенно не подходит. И код для x86 тут вам уже написали. Добавить к нему нечего, если это для обучения, то именно такой и нужен. А если с целями оптимизации кода, то конечно он пишется совсем по другому

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 2):

Например (на гипотетическом RISC без оптимизации), `total = 0; for(i = 0; i < 5; i=i+1) total = total + 1;` так

```
mov r0, #0        // r0: total = 0
mov r1, #5        
mov LP_COUNT, r1  // loop counter (special register)
mov r1, #0        // r1: i = 0
lp  L1            // 
add r0, r0, #1    // begin_of_loop: total = total + 1
add r1, r1, #1    // i = i + 1
L1:               // if --LP_COUNT != 0 goto begin_of_loop
...               // first command after loop
```

и `if(counter > 10) then counter = 0 else counter = counter + 1`

```
// r0: counter
cmp r0, #10    
bgt L1         // counter > 10
add r0, r0, #1 // else counter = counter + 1
b   L2
L1:
sub r0, r0, r0 // then counter = 0
L2:
```

А в некоторых [ISA](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/conditional.html) (Instruction Set Architecture) может быть и такая "экзотика"

```
cmp     r0, #10 
movgt   r0, #0      // if counter > 10 counter = 0
addle   r0, r0, #1  // if counter <= 10 counter = counter + 1
```

с "плотным" потоком команд без переходов (суффиксы задают условное исполнение, команда выполнится по текущему состоянию флагов NZVC, которое было выработано в данном случае предшествующей командой `cmp`)

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта можно посмотреть, как это делает компилятор GCC под 64-битным Linux.

Код программы (файл test.c):

```
void test()
{
    int total, i;
    total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i=i+1)
        total = total + 1;
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

Получился исполняемый файл test, который можно дизассемблировать командой:

```
objdump -M intel -d test
```

В выводе будет такой фрагмент:

```
00000000004004b6 <test>:
  4004b6:       55                      push   rbp
  4004b7:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4004ba:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
  4004c1:       c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
  4004c8:       eb 08                   jmp    4004d2 <test+0x1c>
  4004ca:       83 45 fc 01             add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  4004ce:       83 45 f8 01             add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1
  4004d2:       83 7d f8 04             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x4
  4004d6:       7e f2                   jle    4004ca <test+0x14>
  4004d8:       5d                      pop    rbp
  4004d9:       c3                      ret
```

Первые и последние две инструкции на ассемблере это стандартные вход и выход из функции, они вам не интересны. Что происходит между ними:

1. Присваиваются значения 0 переменным `i` и `total`.
2. Что именно вам интересно (как я понял) - происходит безусловный переход (jmp) на проверку условия цикла (cmp). Это именно и есть реализация "цикла for" на ассемблере. Условие просто проверяется один лишний раз перед выполнением тела цикла.

Comment: А если использовать ещё и флаг `-O3`? Или вопрошающему нужно строгое соответсвие «отдельная команда на C — отдельный и явный набор команд языка ассемблера»?

Comment: @Arhad я думаю уже при O2 все должно свестись к mov eax, 4 :) или оптимизаторы не настолько умны ?

Comment: И интересно почему он решил закодировать `cmp x, 4 / jle` вместо `cmp x, 5 / jl` Сразу видно, что код не человек писал :)

Comment: И кстати, а зачем вы делали объектник и его дизассемблировали, у gcc есть отличный ключик -S который дает на выходе вместо объектника ассемблерный код

Comment: @Mike, [jle vs. jl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572899/why-use-jle-instead-of-jl)

Comment: Чтобы gcc делал "более  человеческий" код я предпочитаю `-S -Os`